# Downloading Passbook files doesn't work with Facebook iOS browser

Tags: facebook, ios6, mobile-safari, mime-types, passbook

Safari for iOS6 supports the mime type: application.com/vnd.apple.pkpass
This means you can download & open Passbook .pkpass files from a URL.

It seems that Facebook's browser does not support this mime type and therefore you can't download Passbook files from within Facebook. Instead you need to 'Open in Safari'. This is a problem because a great way for a business to distribute links to a Passbook promotion (e.g. a coupon, membership, gift card or event ticket) is via a Facebook marketing campaign.

How can I find the right people to contact at Facebook to request that Facebook iOS App browser supports the .pkpass MIME type?

Thanks if you can help,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

This should be working as of the 5.4 version of the Facebook for iOS app.